# loading external secure website and acquiring the specific id to set the value?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

I am trying to create a site where I can retrieve the id of a specific element and set it's value. I have tried doing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>help</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getField(){ 
        window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            console.log('hi')
            console.log(document.getElementById('change_request.short_description').value)

        });
        //document.getElementById('change_request.short_description').value='hello';             
    }   

    </script>

    <body>
        <a href="xxxx.com"  target="_blank" onclick="getField()">SNOW CHANGE</a>
              

    </body>
</html>
```

But my console shows nothing. I am thinking since it is a secure website, I cannot access the id.

But I don't really know whether this is plausible. My question is how do you load the external website then acquire the specific id to set the value?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to get and element from xxxx.com? If yes then you can't just do that. Otherwise, the element is on the same page, you need to wrap the function inside the load event or remove the load completely. Also, in your `getElementById` you have a "." which suggests class name. You can't do that. Use
`querySelectorAll` instead and `[0]` to get the first element only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log('Window Loaded');
        window.getField = function(){ 

              console.log('hi')
              console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#change_request.short_description')[0].value)

          //document.getElementById('change_request.short_description').value='hello';             
        }   
    });
    </script>

    <body>
        <a href="xxxx.com"  target="_blank" onclick="getField()">SNOW CHANGE</a>
        <input id="change_request" class="short_description" value="123" type="text" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes actually the xxxx.com is another external page where the id is change_request.short_description. I wanted to retrieve it and set its value. I guess that's not possible?

Comment: Not the way you're trying to do it with a link and href to the site. You can't just change someone else's website. If it's on the same domain you can iframe it and then change it but I don't get what you're trying to do. Explain the entire concept.

Comment: okay so my goal is to fill in information on the website(xxxx) via the html page that I am designing. for e.g on the website(xxx) we have these fields:
 
implementation plan :
verification plan:

I want to be able to automatically fill in those fields via the webpage I am creating. 
Do you know how to make that possible?

Comment: Unless your website and the xxxx are on the same domain and you load it into iframe you can't do that. I would go for javascript booktmarklet or chrome plugin instead.